# I am try to lookup value from one sheet to another sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Sorry it's my first post so please help me out

I am try to lookup value one sheet to from another sheet with respect to age range and Amount.

Please refer google sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U8pZqSxIVzmVxGMqQhdz_9cKm-sR9b_UfFKAidKL97M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
 =INDEX(Age!$C$2:$K$5,MATCH(B2,Age!B:B,0)-ROW(Age!$B$1),AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN(Age!$C$2:$K$2)-COLUMN(Age!$C$2)+1)/(RIGHT(Age!$C$2:$K$2,2)*1>=C2)/(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(Age!$C$2:$K$2,2),"-","")*1<=C2),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me by putting in cell E2...

```
=index(Age!$B:$K,MATCH($B2,Age!$B:$B,0),sum(filter(if(right(Age!$2:$2,2)+0<C2,1,0),right(Age!$2:$2,2)+0>0))+2)
```

[image]